# Is there a way of getting an image file contents without submitting a form in html/php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, image-uploading

I'm trying to send an image file to MySQL (mediumblob). I can get the contents of a file easily using `file_get_contents($image)` and easily send this to MySQL however, the server I am using does not allow me to submit any uploaded file and therefore cannot get the file contents at all.

Is there a way of just selecting the file, placing it into a variable without submitting the form? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why store the images as blobs in the database, and instead create a secure uploading procedure?

Comment: could you write here what kind of images you try to get url?. is the images in a html content li <html><div><img src=""></div></html>  if you try to get the img url from html content there are many ways to do it

Comment: Hi, the content is just a jpg image, and then just get the contents of it without having to hit a submit button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, try utilizing [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```js
var _files = [];
$("form").on("change", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  _files.push(e.target.files[0]);
  console.log(_files);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form method="POST" action="/abc">
  <input type="file" accepts="image/*" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a pity you cant upload files. However there are several ideas you can try. This is one of them:

1. Read file using javascript. fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d5mg66uw/
2. Upload the file as string using ajax call
3. Save the file on the server

You can easily read file from your computer with javascript like this:

```
function readSingleFile(evt) {
    var f = evt.target.files[0];

    if (f) {
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function (e) {
            var contents = e.target.result;
            alert("Got the file.n" + "name: " + f.name + "n" + "type: " + f.type + "n" + "size: " + f.size + " bytesn" + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n")));
        }
        r.readAsText(f);
    } else {
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
}

document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

the file content will be in the **contents** variable

Then just upload it using

```
$.post('fileuploading.php', {filecontents: contents})
```

and you are done. Either input it to database or save it as an image. What an elegant solution.

FIY: this could get hairy on older browsers

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try it out, I'm not great with JS but will give it a go. Thanks again!